# how to add multiple row from DataGridView to a table in the DataBase?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

in my DataGridView there are about 2 or 3 rows about the Supplier data 
it is about Supplier data ,,as there might be one product i get from 2 or 3 suppliers 
how to add the Suppliers_ID (FK) to the Product table in the data base from the data grid view when i click on a button (Confirm adding) and to avoid the data redundancy 
i think it might be saving the 2 or 3  Suppliers_ID as Records but i donknow how to do this ?

Comment: Your question is incomprehensible.

Comment: i got 2 or 3 records in DataGridView ,, this data about supplier to a product ,, if there are many suppliers to the same products i want that to be in the database as the product table and suppliers table has a relation in the database , how to make these suppliers connected to the same product ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a master-detail relationship between your two tables. This below link is for DataGrid but you can use the same logic for DataGridView:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59y45529(vs.100).aspx

Hope this helps.